# Scripts Works on one scene but error in another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm getting an error which says

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object Explode.LateUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/Explode.cs:40)

I'm not sure why I get this error as everything works fine and I have the exact same script in a different scene without the error message. I'd love any help please.

I'm exploding my player with different coloured boxes.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public class Explode : MonoBehaviour {

        [System.Serializable]
        public class ExplodeColours
        {
            public Color32[] Colours;
        }


        public static bool explode, explodeOnce;
        public ParticleSystem Explodes;
        private ParticleSystem explosionSystem;
        public Transform player;
        public List<ExplodeColours> ColoursList;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SelectedChar", 0);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
            explodeOnce = false;
            explode = false;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
            if (explode == true)
            {
                explodeOnce = true;
                PlayerExplode();
            }
        }
        void LateUpdate()
        {
            if (explode)
            {
                ParticleSystem.Particle[] Particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[explosionSystem.main.maxParticles];
                //ParticleSystem.Particle[] Particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[Explodes.main.maxParticles];
                int NumParticlesAlive = explosionSystem.GetParticles(Particles);
                for (int i = 0; i < NumParticlesAlive; i++)
                {
                    Particles[i].startColor = (ColoursList[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SelectedChar")].Colours[Random.Range(0, ColoursList[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SelectedChar")].Colours.Length)]);
                }
                explosionSystem.SetParticles(Particles, NumParticlesAlive);
                explode = false;
            }

        }
        void PlayerExplode()
        {
            explosionSystem = Instantiate(Explodes, player.position, player.rotation);
            explosionSystem.Play();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your error is on line 40 as the message say, make sure everything that is called is instantiated in this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is line 40 (I had to count):

```
ParticleSystem.Particle[] Particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[explosionSystem.main.maxParticles];
```

Then `explosionSystem` or `main` or `maxParticles` is null. I'm going to close this as a duplicate, this error is so common and the way to resolve it is easy.

But a break point on the line of code, when the code control halts, check which object is null and make sure its set.

**EDIT**:

Use the `GetComponent` to initialize the `explosionSystem` variable in the `Start` function.First, find the GameObject the `ParticleSystem` is attached to the use `GetComponent` to get the `ParticleSystem`.

```
private ParticleSystem explosionSystem;
void Start()
{
    GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("NameOfObjectParticleSystemIsAttachedTo");
    explosionSystem = obj.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
}
```

---

Also, inside the `for` loop, you tried to use Particles's `startColor`  property without initializing each one. You can do that with `Particles[i] = new ParticleSystem.Particle();`.

Change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumParticlesAlive; i++)
{
    Particles[i].startColor 
 = (ColoursList[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SelectedChar")].Colours[Random.Range(0, ColoursList[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SelectedChar")].Colours.Length)]);
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumParticlesAlive; i++)
{
    Particles[i] = new ParticleSystem.Particle();
    Particles[i].startColor 
 = (ColoursList[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SelectedChar")].Colours[Random.Range(0, ColoursList[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SelectedChar")].Colours.Length)]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and yes I know this is a common error but the script works fine in one scene and I get an error in another. Everything that I can see is set so I can't see why it won't work.

Comment: Please, please, please do yourself a huge favour and learn how to debug code. Your `explosionSystem` is null. You need to work out why it wasn't instantiated. We can't do this for you without all the source code. Watch some debugging videos. This is a good/easy problem to learn debugging to solve: put the code in a try catch, put a breakpoint on the Catch, when the exception occurs, hover your mouse over the variables making sure everything is set. You've missed something. Ps If I reopened this you'll likely get downvotes and then someone else will close it as a duplicate anyway.

Comment: I @Jeremy and Toby, I have modified to add here OP has messed up and the fix. Hopefully, your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the null reference error, make sure all variables (which are using) has values other wise at least assign default values in constructor level